# Acessibility: Using ARIA role="group" within nested list (ul)

Tags: html, list, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a list of agenda items I want to display.
For that I would use a simple `ul`.

The thing is that within this list I have grouped the items by month. So in general they are sorted by date and now they are also grouped by month.

Example:

```
January 2010
- Item 1
– Item 2

February 2010
- Item 3
– Item 4

March 2010
- Item 5
– Item 6
```

How could I make this information more accessible.

I found this POST about `role="group"` which seems to be right here?!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_group_role

So would the following structure make sense?

```
<ul>
  <li role="group">
    <h3>January 2010</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li role="group">
    <h3>February 2010</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or how would I make clear that the nested ul is a group.

Or would I leave away the nested uls, build everything with a single `ul` with equal `li` for every entry?

Or would I do something like:

```
<div role="list">
  <div>
    <h3 id="label-1">January 2010</h3>
    <ul aria-labelledby="label-1" role="group">
      <div role="listitem">Item 1</div>
      <div role="listitem">Item 2</div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3 id="label-2">February 2010</h3>
    <ul aria-labelledby="label-2" role="group">
      <div role="listitem">Item 3</div>
      <div role="listitem">Item 4</div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would be very glad for some inputs.

Thank you in advance.
cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`role="group"` is not intended for use on non-interactive items. It is designed to group controls such as inputs, buttons together or for grouping elements that are related.

Your third example is closest to the way this should be structured. The headings are great for quick navigation (as heading levels are one of the primary ways screen reader users navigate a page) and the relationships are created within the HTML itself, removing the need for any extra WAI-ARIA.

Yet again there is no need for `role="group"`.

The following example would be perfectly acceptable and accessible. I have change it to a set of listed `<ul>` and `<li>` as that is semantically correct and removes the need for any WAI-ARIA there also. (Golden rule, use semantic elements if you can as support is 100% for those, [support for WAI-ARIA is a little patchy still.](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/) and so should be used for complimentary information / if there is no way to achieve the desired document structure / relationships using standard HTML5 elements.)

Obviously if the Items 1 to 4 are interactive elements and you have left that out for brevity then that is a different matter entirely and I will change this answer.

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3>January 2010</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>February 2010</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. A comprehensible and good answer. I have no controls, so I should be fine. Thanks for clarification though. 

Comment: `role="group"` is not intended for grouping buttons or inputs. It's used for grouping items that belong in a hierarchical structure such as a tree. 

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#document_structure_roles

Dropdown Menu Example
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_group_role#Example_2_Using_the_group_role_with_a_HTML_drop-down_menu

Comment: @CalebTaylor - I was trying to find an actual button group example for you from W3C but can't find it, no doubt it is buried in a completely unrelated document. However https://www.digitala11y.com/group-role/ is from a pretty decent source and the link above covers inputs. You just took the examples to be the only use case, if you check the W3C link you posted it clearly states "A set of user interface objects", which covers anything. See https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#dfn-widget for definition of widget as that is also relevant.

Comment: Made a minor amend to my answer as my definition was too narrow as I only included controls, have now fixed to include any related elements, thanks @CalebTaylor

Comment: not a problem, to be fair I spend more time tying to get my head around documentation then I do actually writing code. I wish they just said "here are 50 examples of how you can use this" instead of thousands of words with vague meaning! hehe!